# SystemExit when starting a new Scrapy project

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying to start a scrapy project following [the scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html). I use `scrapy startproject phdscrapper` from windows PowerShell which causing an "open with" dialogue box to open. I use select my distribution of Python 2.7 which is Canopy.

This opens a new Canopy tab with the following:

```
#!C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Scripts\python.exe

from scrapy.cmdline import execute
execute()
```

I run this code but it produces the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-09737cc1be0e> in <module>()
      1 from scrapy.cmdline import execute
----> 2 execute()

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.pyc in execute(argv, settings)
    126     if not cmdname:
    127         _print_commands(settings, inproject)
--> 128         sys.exit(0)
    129     elif cmdname not in cmds:
    130         _print_unknown_command(settings, cmdname, inproject)

SystemExit: 0
```

After reading through the [Python exception documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) for `SystemExit`, I'm no closer to understanding what the error was or what caused it, could somebody explain the error? Thanks.

Additional information:

In the end I managed to get `startproject` to work but only when using python and passing arguments to `execute`. Using the ipython interpreter the SystemExit 'error' is still displayed even when the code runs successfully. Running the same code from python at the PS prompt doesn't produce this error and the cmd prompt doesn't work (unknown command error). I still can't get Scrapy to work from the PS prompt, as soon as `scrapy` is read an 'open with' dialogue box pops up and anything written after `scrapy` is ignored.

Comment: you are executing nothing

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the code it had generated after the PowerShell would 'initialise' a project by creating the files describe in the docs (scrapy.cfg, __init.py, item.py etc.). I've tried modifying the code to `execute(['scrapy','startproject', 'test'])` and `execute(scrapy startproject test)`, but they produce a `SystemExit` or `SyntaxError`, respectively.
Have I misunderstood what the command `startproject` is supposed to do? I have code for a spider which I named Euraxess but `execute(['scrapy','crawl', 'Euraxess'])` produces a `SystemExit` as well.

Comment: I don't use windows or  canopy but I imagine you are to create your spider in that tab and run it there using the execute command. You can also just run your commands from the shell as per the link I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error shows nothing is passed in, you should be passing something like:

```
execute(['scrapy','crawl','my_spider])
```

You can run the commands from your shell or use the `execute` command in your script.

All the commands are listed [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html)

Comment: In the end I managed to get `startproject` to work but only when using python and passing arguments to `execute`. Using the ipython interpreter the SystemExit 'error' is still displayed even when the code runs successfully. Running the same code from python at the PS prompt doesn't produce this error and the cmd prompt doesn't work (unknown command error). I still can't get Scrapy to work from the PS prompt, as soon as `scrapy` is read an 'open with' dialogue box pops up and anything written after `scrapy` is ignored.